# Как сделать доступным свое приложение на GlassFish другим клиентам?

Tags: glassfish

Я задеплоил проект на GlassFish и хочу к нему подключиться с другого клиента.

Как можно это сделать и какой адрес нужно при этом указывать?

Answer (score 1):

1. Указывать нужно адрес компьютера, на котором развёрнут GlassFish.
2. GlassFish должен слушать свой порт на этом адресе и иметь разрешение на приём соединений на этом адресе.

Comment: я читал что  для доступа к другому компьютеру, нужно его внешний(белый) айпи, который можно заказать за деньги у провайдера, просто сейчас пытаюсь зайти с другого клиента, указывая мой обычный айди и порт. И ничего..

Comment: Для доступа через Интернет нужен "белый" IP, для доступа из локальной сети достаточно "серого".